# How can I troubleshoot why packets aren't coming back from Hyper-V host to guest?

Tags: vpn, routing, hyper-v, anyconnect

I have a Win11 host ("Host") running Hyper-V and I have a Win10 guest ("Guest"). My Win11 host may connect to the Internet via Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

***Without*** VPN connected, Internet connectivity from Guest to the Internet works as expected: I can ping 8.8.8.8 and resolve DNS.

***With*** VPN connected, Internet connectivity from Host is fine, but doesn't seem to work at all in Guest: I can't ping 8.8.8.8 and can't resolve DNS.

I'm trying to understand how I can troubleshoot where the failure is happening.

***With*** the VPN connected, I've tried:

- At Guest, Flushing the ARP cache and observed that the correct MAC address is obtained for the gateway. (The gateway is the IP address of the Hyper-V interface on Host.)
- At Host, run Wireshark, capturing on the Hyper-V interface and I can see packets going *from* Guest's interface *to* the gateway, but I don't see any packets going the other way, i.e., I don't see any packets going from gateway to Guest. **If I disconnect the VPN**, I will immediately see packets going from the gateway to Guest.

I thought this might mean there's a routing problem: the packets don't know how to get back to guest because of a route added by the VPN. But I tried adding a route for `172.18.79.191` (the IP address of the Guest interface) with a mask of `255.255.255.255` and a metric of `1`, but this didn't seem to make any difference. I'm not entirely sure I did this correctly, but it looked sensible when viewed via `route print`.

Given I have four interfaces in play (Host-Internet, Host-VPN, Host-Hyper-V, and Guest), I'm not sure how to go about following the packets and finding where it goes wrong.

Can anybody suggest how I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Could you attach outputs of "route print" for 3 states: 1) host without established VPN; 2) host with established VPN; 3) guest